# "Parameterizations are non-unique", how can we prove it?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, curves, parametrization

$$
\textbf{"Parameterizations are non-unique"}
$$
I have seen this statement in several books and at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation).

However, I have never seen a proof of the statement. How can we prove it?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, what it says is that they are *generally* nonunique. But if you have a parametrization of a curve $\gamma\colon[a,b]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, you can always define, say,$$\begin{array}{rccc}\gamma^\star\colon&[a+1,b+1]&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{R}^n\\&t&\mapsto&\gamma(t-1)\end{array}$$and that's another parametrization.